# how to update,delete ,... post after scrolling down ,up,right and left in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, updates, delete-row

I have faced a problem.
I am working with recyclerview. I want the list post get updated When users scroll down and when they scroll to the left, the program call the post deletion function. And by scrolling to the right,the program calls updating post function. I wrote codes below. Could you explain with examples how I can do this? I wrote these functions but I failed.

CustomListAdapterForPostOrga

```
public class CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Posts> post;
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
private boolean loading;
private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


     public CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan(Activity activity, List<Posts> post) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.post = post;
   }



     public CustomListAdapterForPostOrgan(List<Posts> post, RecyclerView recyclerView) {

      this.post = post;

       if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

       final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
            .getLayoutManager();


          recyclerView
            .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                       int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                            .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (!loading
                            && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        // End has been reached
                        // Do something
                        if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        loading = true;
                    }
                }
            });
}}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

///////////////////
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return post.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return post.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_organ_news
                , null);



    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.organ_news__avatar_show_thumbnail);
    TextView titr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_organ_news_list_organ);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date_posts_organ);
    TextView fi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cunter_for_organ_posts);

    // getting billionaires data for the row
    Posts m = post.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getAvatar(), imageLoader);




    // Wealth Source
    year.setText("Wealth Source: " + String.valueOf(m.getPublish_at()));


    titr.setText(String.valueOf(m.getTitle()));

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getPublish_at()));
    fi.setText(String.valueOf(m.getView_count()));

    return convertView;
}
   public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    }
}
```

in main function:

```
private void handelpost(final List<Post> posts, Page pages) {

    if (pages.getCurrentPage() > 1) {

    } else {

        recycler_post.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        final AdapterRcycelerViewPostOrgan
                madapter = new
                AdapterRcycelerViewPostOrgan(posts);
        recycler_post.setAdapter(madapter);
        recycler_post.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        madapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                posts.add(null);
                madapter.notifyItemInserted(posts.size() - 1);
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        posts.remove(posts.size() - 1);
                        madapter.notifyItemRemoved(posts.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = posts.size();
                        int end = start + 20;

                   /*     for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
                            studentList.add(new Student("Student " + i, "AndroidStudent" + i + "@gmail.com"));
                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size());
                        }*/
                   //     posts.set()
                        //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 2000);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

I want to know how I can do this function on my own lists. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In onScrolled callback you have dx and dy. If dy>0 list is being scrolled down and if dy<0 its being scrolled up. Same with dx, just different axis